# get value of specific attribute of given bazel target

Tags: bazel

I am sure this is documented somewhere but unable to find the answer anywhere.

if I have:

````
```bazel_rule(
    name = "foo",
    srcs = ["foo.cpp"],
    attr_bar = "bar"
)```
````

if I have a reference to this rule (`//src:foo`) in a Starlark (.bzl) file, how can I query the target to get a value of a specific attribute. e.g. `get_attribute("//src:foo", "attr_bar")` should return "bar" in this example.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on whether you're trying to read the attribute from a [macro](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/macros.html), a [rule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/rules.html), or an [aspect](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/aspects.html).

Short answers:

A macro can't read attributes of a target (roughly, macros are evaluated at build file loading time, and attributes are evaluated later at analysis time). You can do things like taking in the attributes you care about and creating the rule (`bazel_rule` in your example) within the macro, so that the macro has the attribute value, but this usually quickly becomes messy and hard to follow.

A Starlark rule also can't directly read attribute values from dependencies (it can read its own attributes though, of course). The rule you're interested in (`bazel_rule` here) has to put the information in a [provider](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/rules.html#providers) and the Starlark rule reads the provider from its dependencies.

An aspect can read the attributes of the rule its being evaluated on directly through `ctx.rule.attr.<attr_name>`([the example here](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/aspects.html#aspect-implementation) does this).

Comment: Thank you! Context: I'm building ROS packages with bazel, its build system has a concept of packageFoo declaring dependencies which it does not itself require, but any package that depends on Foo needs to depend on.

So I'd like to create macro with a param "deps2" such that when A depends on B, A puts B's "deps2" in its own "deps" attribute.

I am using the word attribute loosely, what I really need is just for A to read B's "deps2" param.

I also tried this using a rule, but I would need to wrap one rule in another, and within the wrapper update ctx.attrs.deps, which is frozen.

Comment: This sounds similar to `java_library`'s `exports` attribute: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/java.html#java_library.exports Are you working with your own starlark rules, native rules, or someone else's rules?

Comment: If you're working with your own rule, let's call it `ros_package`, the way I'd do it is add an attribute to `ros_package` called `exports` (or whatever you want), and in the implementation for `ros_package`, read the `exports` and put that into a provider, say `RosInfo`. Also in the impl for `ros_package` you read the `RosInfo` providers from dependencies, read the `exports` off the providers and add that to the deps within the rule.

Comment: thank you very much for you thoughtful replies. I am using  rules_foreign_cc, have filed an FR under that repository https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc/issues/88.